# VS CODE / MSBUILD : error MSB1003: Specify a project or solution file. The current working directory does not contain a project or solution file

Tags: visual-studio-code, .net-core

I've tried many different ways but I get the error MSBUILD : error MSB1003: Specify a project or solution file. The current working directory does not contain a project or solution file. in Visual Studio code when trying to run my Net Core.

I think I have this configured correctly.  The project builds with no errors.  I even tried building a new empty project and still get the error.

launch.json

```
{
// Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
// Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
// For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
"version": "0.2.0",
"configurations": [
    {
        "name": ".NET Core Launch (web)",
        "type": "coreclr",
        "request": "launch",
        "preLaunchTask": "build",
        "program": "${workspaceFolder}/API/API/bin/Debug/net5.0/API.dll",
        "args": [],
        "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}",
        "stopAtEntry": false,
        "serverReadyAction": {
            "action": "openExternally",
            "pattern": "\\bNow listening on:\\s+(https?://\\S+)"
        },
        "env": {
            "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
        },
        "sourceFileMap": {
            "/Views": "${workspaceFolder}/Views"
        }
    }
    

]
```

}

Tasks.json

```
{
// See https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=733558
// for the documentation about the tasks.json format
"version": "2.0.0",
"tasks": [
    {
        "label": "build",
        "command": "dotnet",
        "type": "shell",
        "args": [
            "build",
            // Ask dotnet build to generate full paths for file names.
            "/property:GenerateFullPaths=true",
            // Do not generate summary otherwise it leads to duplicate errors in Problems panel
            "/consoleloggerparameters:NoSummary"
        ],
        "group": "build",
        "presentation": {
            "reveal": "silent"
        },
        "problemMatcher": "$msCompile"
    }
]
```

}

Comment: What does the folder structure look like?

Comment: I mean the dir is C:\Users\[UserName]\source\repos\Git\FSF\API\API\bin\Debug\net5.0\API.dll to the DLL

Comment: @MattU any thoughts?

Comment: The `args` for the build in `tasks.json` typically contains the path. So after the `"build",` line it'd be something like `"${workspaceFolder}/ProjectName.csproj",`. Have you tried that?